# Fluent Validation Rule

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I used Fluent Validator. I need to create own rule. For example:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class AddressValidator:AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Street).NotEmpty().When(a => BeAValidAddress(a.Street));
    }

    private bool BeAValidAddress(string adress)
    {
        //...some logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use Validate method of AddressValidator class IsValid property is always true. Even if in BeAValidAddress method is only "return false". Maybe I forgot something important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try must, I always use it

```
RuleFor(a => a.Street).Must(x => x=="hello"); 
//will return false untill a.street == hello
```

or

```
RuleFor(a => a.Street).Must(BeAValidAddress())

private bool BeAValidAddress(string adress)
{
    //...some logic
    return false;
}
```

or

```
RuleFor(a => a.Street).Must(x => BeAValidAddress(x))

private bool BeAValidAddress(string adress)
{
    //...some logic
    return false;
}
```

all this mean the same.

Comment: glad it helped, you should mark it as answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of `Fluent Validation`.

```
The When and Unless methods can be used to specify conditions that control
when the rule should execute.
```

Then you rule never will work because the `BeAValidAddress` always return `false`.

Comment: My fault. I used "When" but I not read documentation to the end. Now I know my mistake and I know how to create more complicated rules. Thank you very much